# Deserialize JSON Array returned from HTTP-Response

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I'm having trouble deserializing an JSON string to a class i Wrote.

Here are my Classes

```
class Newsletter
{
public string id;
public string state;
public string html;
public string name;
}


class ApiReply
{
    int success;
    //string value;
    int status;
    string reason;
}


class Newsletterlist : ApiReply
{
    private const string URL = "https://www.newsletter2go.de/de/api/get/newsletters/";
    public string key { private set; get; }
    public  Newsletterlist()
    {

        key = "MYAPIKEY";
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] data = PostData.get_postData(this);
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        dynamic temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
    }

    public List<Newsletter> value {private set;get;}


}
```

I want to deserialize the JSON Return String into my Object Newsletterlist,
but inside the JSON String, there's an JSON Array and I don't know how to deserialize the JSON Array to List Value.

The JSON String looks something like this:

```
{
success : 0,
value :  [],  <--  Value may contain a JSON Array wich I want to Serialize to List<Newsletter>
status :405,
reason : “Method Not Allowed , POST Required”
}
```

Comment: You need to know what is going to be returned to you in the array, if its just an array of string values then have value as a `List<string>` if its a complex type then create an object that matches it and have a `List<ComplexType>`

Comment: The String returned from the call mentioned above looks like this:
"{\"success\":1,\"value\":[{\"id\":\"628461\",\"state\":\"draft\",\"html\":\"SOME-HTML-CODE\",\"name\":\"Neues Mailing\"}],\"status\":200,\"reason\":\"OK\"}"

I hope I'm understanding your answer.. so there's no way i can deserialize that array into an array of Type Newsletter[ ] , because the Newsletter Class matches the array Response.

Comment: See below answer for a rough example.. just change the SomeType to match the object you are being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know what is going to be returned to you in the array, if its just an array of string values then have value as a `List<string>` if its a complex type then create an object that matches it and have a `List<ComplexType>`

```
class ApiReply
{
    int success {get;set}
    List<string> value {get;set;}
    int status {get;set;}
    string reason {get;set;}
}
```

or with complex type:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

class ApiReply
{
    int success {get;set}
    List<SomeType> value {get;set;}
    int status {get;set;}
    string reason {get;set;}
}
```

And the JSON for that would look like this:

```
{
success : 0,
value :  [{name="fred", age=21},{name="paul", age=53}],  <--  Value may contain a JSON Array
status :405,
reason : “Method Not Allowed , POST Required”
}
```

Example with Complex child array:[JSONConvert.DeserializeObject not handling child array with unnamed array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499701/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-not-handling-child-array-with-unnamed-array-items)